# Creating a mini-game

Tags: java, game-physics

Hey Im a little stuck i have been looking for the best way to create this type of minigame
basically players will enter a lobby(they now get stored in either a map or array) then when the game starts the game will randomly select 1 person from the map or array to become infected(now remove this player from the map/array to the infected map/array)

how would i go about doing this i have tried it before but i end up failing.

so far i have something like this setup just to test it out

```
    private static HashMap<String, Integer> infected = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

private static HashMap<String, Integer> survivors = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

private static HashMap<String, Integer> lobby = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

i am trying to store random names in there as we speak and will test it out

Comment: What's connection between the `String` and `Integer` in the `Map`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably keep a "master" list of all available players.  From there I'd simply create a reference list of "Infected" players.

You would then be able to determine if a player is infected or not by simply calling `contains` on the "Infected" list.

Need more info though...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `HashMap` is really the right data structure, perhaps consider making a class of players that contain a collection of 'Buffs', your `Game` could either maintain multiple lists of infected players but it may be simpler to find that player in a single list.

```
interface Moveable {
    public void forward;
    public void back;
    public void left;
    public void right;
}

interface Buffable {
    public void addBuff(Buff buff);
    public void removeBuff(Buff buff);
    public boolean hasBuff(Buff buff);
}

class Player implements Moveable, Buffable {
    private String name;
    private int health;
    private List<Buff> buffs;

    /*
     contructor etc
     */

    public void addBuff(Buff buff) {
        buffs.add(buff);
    }

    public void removeBuff(Buff buff) {
        buffs.remove(buff);
    }

    public void hasBuff(Buff buff) {
        return buffs.contains(buff);
    }
}

class Game {
    private List<Player> players;
    private List<Player> infected;

    /*
     constructor etc
     */

    public void infect(int player) {
        Player p = players.get(player);
        p.addBuff(new Infection());
        infected.add(p); // see or
    }
    // or
    public List<Player> getInfectedPlayers() {
        List<Player> ret = new List<Player>();
        Buff b = new Infection();

        for (Player p : players) {
            if (p.hasBuff(b)) {
                ret.add(p);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```